# Opencv contour area returns wrong result

Tags: python, opencv, contour

I am currently working on a opencv project which determines the contour area.
I tried to make a proper threshold and apply `cv2.findContours` on it.
However, I found that when the contour is intersecting the borders of the image, the area is drastically underestimated using `cv2.contourArea`.
How can solve this issue?
(Please check the attached images which demonstrates the wrong result on a sample image)

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def midpoint(ptA, ptB):
    return ((ptA[0] + ptB[0]) * 0.5, (ptA[1] + ptB[1]) * 0.5)

Input = cv2.imread("Thresh.png")
Thresh = cv2.cvtColor(Input,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(Thresh,  cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
minArea = 0
for cnt in contours:
    area = cv2.contourArea(cnt)
    print(area)
    if (area > minArea) :
        x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
        rect = cv2.minAreaRect(cnt)
        box = cv2.boxPoints(rect)
        box = np.int0(box)
        Input = cv2.drawContours(Input,[box],0,(255,0,0),2)
        (tl, tr, br, bl) = box
        (tltrX, tltrY) = midpoint(tl, tr)
        cv2.putText(Input, "{:1f}".format(area),
        (int(tltrX), int(tltrY)), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,
        0.65, (0, 255, 0), 2)
        cv2.imshow('Input',Input)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[Input threshold image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mgoDO.png)
[Determined contours (bounding rectangle) with written contour areas on it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dPL59.png)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I edited th title and also tried to write down the required details and attach the corresponding result on a picture.

Comment: What do you expect the result to be for this image?

Comment: As you can see, in second image area of the biggest contour is determined as 71 which is considerably lower than the correct value(namely more than 40000) . Just look at the tiny contour on the left for which the contour area is determined as 193.

Comment: Perhaps you need to pad the image with black before getting the contour.

Comment: @sames did you solve this? I am experiencing exactly the same problem